# failed running solr

Tags: solr, drupal-7, jetty, ubuntu-11.10

i have installed solr-jetty on ubuntu 11.10. when i run `http://localhost:8080/solr` ,yes it's can. but when i tried to open `http://localhost:8080/solr/admin`, shown message "page not found"

i tried to run solr with code:

```
java -jar /usr/share/jetty/start.jar
```

this is the screen out:

```
 agan@dancing:~$ java -jar /usr/share/jetty/start.jar
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:179)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

how to run solr on ubuntu 11.10 server?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to start the Solr instance on command line. In your solr folder solr/example directory you can find the start.jar file over there. Just log into your server through the command line and find that start.jar file and then hit `java -jar start.jar` command and it will start the solr instance.

Comment: i have start using `java -jar /usr/share/jetty/start.jar` but stop with message above (see my post above)

Comment: Did you added the solr.xml file?

Comment: solrconfig.xml in my `/etc/solr/home/conf/` dir,
is that?

Comment: no that's the different... in jetty container or tomcat container you have to create one file solr.XML. follow this link for installation. [Link](http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/12/30/installing-apache-solr-on-centos/)